# Implementing algorithm for rating post

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I am working in PHP to develop an algorithm. I have some one million posts. Every post has many comments, likes and views.

For example : there is 3 posts.

- Post 1 rating is 3000 (I have a fixed formula to calculate this result using comments, likes and views)
- Post 2: 2000
- Post 3: 1000

while storing these post i have saved time using time(); also called as  Unix timestamp

- Post 1 time:  1352099640 (rating is 3000)
- Post 2 time : 1352099660 (rating is 2000)
- Post 3 time : 1352099680 (rating is 1000)

I have following conditions to display posts;

1. Display post who have high ratings
2. If the post is getting older than other posts but having high ratings than others . display this kind of post below the post who have high ranking in minimum time.

I am considering two things .

1. High rating of Post
2. Time of Post.

If post having high rates in minimum time then it will be 1st post on the site. If Post having high rates in max time then it will be second post .. How i can write down the conditions

How I can write these kind of conditions in PHP?

Comment: [Here is one approach](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=231209). There are basically infinite number of possibilities - depending on how you want the final ranking to behave (how important is time, should a post decay linearly over time?...)

Comment: For clarification, is your algorithm designed and implemented, and you're just looking for advice to display your posts?

Comment: @SSK do these rating take into account the time, or are you asking to come up with a system that takes into account the rating and the time then decides which order to display the posts in?

Comment: check i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not so much a programing issue as it is a design issue. If the intent is the higher the rating the higher the post is displayed, then check sort the ratings and descend down the list starting by putting the post with the highest rating at the top. If this isn't what you want than this is more of an issue of the algorithm not being clear.

Comment: I am considering two things . 1) High rating of Post 2) Time of Post. If post having high rates in minimum time then it will be 1st post on the site. If Post having high rates in max time then it will be second post .. How i can write down the conditions :)

Comment: So just to clarify you're only concerned with the top two posts being displayed?

Comment: I think you need to come up with a formula that takes rating and time and gives you an order to display the posts. For example order=ranking/time so the higher order is the closer to the top it is displayed, is that what you want?

Comment: yes this can be done !! How i can write this formula. I have tried this one  (p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5
where p = points and t = age in hours
But i am not getting proper output

Comment: Can you show your code with an example input and output? Is each "post" an object or what? How do you access the variables that store rate and time? For future reference questions are a lot easier to work with if you copy and paste your code into them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19080/discussion-between-ssk-and-celeritas)